# z-test in statsmodel with known variance/std

Tags: z-test, statsmodels

To my knowledge: If I have a small Gaussian distributed data set and I know the true variance $\sigma$ of the data then the z-test is only appropriate if the standard deviation of the estimator is set to $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$. 
with:

- $n$ is the sample size (data size).

In statsmodel the function `sm.stats.ztest` don't has a parameter for the true standard deviation. The function computes the standard deviation of the estimator from the data $\sigma_{\mathcal D}/\sqrt{n}$. This gives another result (in this case a t-test is more appropriate).

I illustrate it by an example (adapted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test):

Suppose that in a particular geographic region, the mean and standard deviation of scores on a reading test is 100 points, and 12 points, respectively. Our interest is in the scores of 5 students in a particular school who received a mean score of 90.4. We can ask whether this mean score is significantly lower than the regional mean—that is, are the students in this school comparable to a simple random sample of 5 students from the region as a whole, or are their scores surprisingly low?

**Parameter of Interest**: $\mu$, population mean.

**Null Hypothesis:** $\mu$ = 100

**Alternative Hypthosis:** $\mu$ < 100

5 Students with $\mu_e = 90.4$.

```py
loc=mu_0=100
scale=12
n=5

np.random.seed(40) 
data = np.random.normal(loc=96, scale=scale, size=n)
sigma_data = data.std(ddof=1)
mu_data = data.mean()
print(mu_data)

# compute the p-value
std_mu_estimator = scale/np.sqrt(n) # note we know the true std of the data
p_value = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(mu_data, mu_0, sigma_data/std_mu_estimator)
print ("p-value with true std: ", p_value)

# statsmodel is using the data std to calculate the estimator std
# for a z-test is seems not to be the correct way???
print("statsmodel:", sm.stats.ztest(data, value = mu_0, alternative = "smaller"))
# same result as
p_value = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(mu_data, mu_0, sigma_data/np.sqrt(n))
print ("p-value with estiamted std (from data): ", p_value)
```

```
90.39845578565013
p-value with true std:  9.39939613111886e-06
statsmodel: (-1.7827917200700583, 0.03731010705030108)
p-value with estiamted std (from data):  0.03731010705030108
```

Note: Here the difference is quite small, but if the sample size is smaller it becomes more relevant.

Why does `statsmodel` don't have a parameter to set the variance or std of the estimator for a z-test? To my knowledge providing a true std is meaningful for a z-test (in contrast to a t-test).

Thanks for your answer.

Note: In R the z-Test enforces you to enter the value for the standard deviation, e.g.:

```
z.test(data, mu=10)
Error in z.test(data, mu = 10) : You must enter the value for sigma.x
```

Comment: "*Our interest is in the scores of 5 students in a particular school who received a mean score of 90.4. We can ask whether this mean score is significantly lower than the regional mean*" ... if *seeing* the score was what caused you to ask the question, you [can't test it on the same data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data).

Comment: The regional mean is 100 (null-hypothesis)- this is not the data from the school. The data from the school is 90.4. So the null hypothesis is based on other data.  The example is (with different n and mu_data) from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test

Comment: I didn't say anything about $\mu_0$ whatever. That's not the issue I was raising at all.